# Solving recurrence using analogy with continuous $x_{n+1} = \frac{r^2}{2d - x_n}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

What's up lovely friends, I'm facing a physics problem and felt on a recurrence that one does not see everyday. This one:

$x_{n+1} = \frac{r^2}{2d - x_n}$

or

$f(n+1) = \frac{a}{b-f(n)}$ if you will

the thing is, I know the solution for the continuous analogue of this:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{a}{b-y} - y$

I wonder if anyone can help me on how to solve it using the continuous comparison.

How to solve the integral case ?

$\frac{dy}{\frac{a}{b-y} - y} = dx$

the LHS is integrable it will give some log and arctan involving y. 
Does the discrete case I have to solve an ugly sum like this ?

Summation by parts looks really tempting here

Comment: May I ask for the physics problem?

Comment: The problem is to find the potentital over a conducting sphere(radius $r$) which had at the beggining some potential $V$ after we put it on a distance $d > r$ of a zero-potential conducting plane. The link that I have is in portuguese: http://200.17.141.35/egsantana/elecmagnet/campo_electrico/imagenes/imagenes.htm

Comment: I see, this problem is identical to the problem of finding the capacitance of 2 identical spheres separated by a distance. As far as I know, only series solution exist.

Comment: Nice, do you know any link where I can see the solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternate way to solve the problem is rewrite $x_n$ as $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ where $p_n, q_n$ are sequences to be determined. The recurrence relation becomes

$$\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}} = \frac{r^2 q_n}{2d q_n - p_n}$$
We can transform this to a sort of linear equation
$$\begin{bmatrix}p_{n+1} \\ q_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}
\propto \begin{bmatrix}0 & r^2\\ -1 & 2d\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}p_{n} \\ q_{n}\end{bmatrix}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{bmatrix}x_{n} \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
\propto
\begin{bmatrix}p_{n} \\ q_{n}\end{bmatrix}
\propto \begin{bmatrix}0 & r^2\\ -1 & 2d\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0 & r^2\\ -1 & 2d\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues 
$\alpha_{\pm} = d \pm \sqrt{d^2-r^2}$ with eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} \alpha_{\mp} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.
Since we can decompose the initial vector as
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
= \frac{x_1 - \alpha_{-}}{\alpha_{+}-\alpha_{-}}
\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{+}\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
+ \frac{\alpha_{+} - x_1}{\alpha_{+}-\alpha_{-}}
\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{-}\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
We get
$$\begin{bmatrix}x_n \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
\propto (x_1 - \alpha_{-})\alpha_{-}^{n-1}
\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{+}\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
+ (\alpha_{+} - x_1) \alpha_{+}^{n-1}
\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_{-}\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
This leads to
$$x_n = r^2 \frac{
(x_1 - \alpha_{-})\alpha_{-}^{n-2} + (\alpha_{+} - x_1)\alpha_{+}^{n-2}
}{
(x_1 - \alpha_{-})\alpha_{-}^{n-1} + (\alpha_{+} - x_1)\alpha_{+}^{n-1}
}
= r^2 \frac{f_{n-1} - x_1 f_{n-2}}{f_{n} - x_1 f_{n-1}}
$$
where $f_n = \alpha_{+}^n - \alpha_{-}^n$.
In particular, if $d > r > 0$, then $|\alpha_{+}| > |\alpha_{-}|$ and $f_n$ will be dominated by $\alpha_{+}^n$ term for large $n$. This implies

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \frac{r^2}{\alpha_{+}} = \alpha_{-} = d - \sqrt{d^2-r^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Long time ago, I faced a similar problem and, searching my notes, I found the following result (may I confess that I did not find how I arrived to it). It write $$x_n=\frac{a^n+K b^n}{a^{n+1}+K b^{n+1}}$$ with $$a=\frac{d-\sqrt{d^2-r^2}}{r^2}~~~~~~~~~~\,~~~~~~~~~~ b=\frac{d+\sqrt{d^2-r^2}}{r^2}$$ the constant $K$ being defined by initial conditions.

What you can notice is that $d\pm\sqrt{d^2-r^2}$ are the roots of equation $x = \frac{r^2}{2d - x}$

For the differential equation you seem to have solved it;  the result is $$x+C=\frac{b }{\sqrt{4
   a-b^2}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 y-b}{\sqrt{4 a-b^2}}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(a-b y+y^2\right)$$ I wish you a lot of fun for extracting $y$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: ty, I also have no clue of where you took this result from

Comment: @onlyme. This is exactly what I meant : I found the results in ooold notes for a quite similar problem but, unfortunatly, nothing else.

Comment: Q.: Where are these formula coming from? A.: Nothing mysterious, really, simply the general principle that *iterating a function is easier when axes are centered at a fixed point*. Here, the function is $x\mapsto r^2/(2d-x)$ hence assume that $u=r^2/(2d-u)$ and consider $$z_n=x_n-u$$ Simple computations yield $$z_{n+1}=\frac{uz_n}{2d-u-z_n}$$ that is, $$\frac1{z_{n+1}}=\frac{2d-u}u\,\frac1{z_n}-\frac1u$$  This is an affine transform, easy to iterate, especially if one centers again around the fixed point to get a linear recursion. .../...

Comment: .../... This idea yields $$\frac1{z_{n+1}}-\frac1{2(d-u)}=\frac{2d-u}{u}\,\left(\frac1{z_n}-\frac1{2(d-u)}\right)$$ thus, $$\frac{1}{x_n-u}=\left(\frac{2d-u}{u}\right)^n\,\left(\frac1{x_0-u}-\frac1{2(d-u)}\right)+\frac{1}{2(d-u)}$$ from which one can deduce $x_n$.

Comment: @Did. Thanks to you, I shall be able to add this to my almost 50 years old notes. Thank you.

Comment: More symmetrical formulas use both fixed points $u$ and $v$ of the function to be iterated, for example, $$\frac{x_n-u}{x_n-v}=\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)^n\frac{x_0-u}{x_0-v}$$